# What does an arduino sketch translate to before compilation?

Tags: avr, esp8266

I've been experimenting with Arduino on both esp8266 and AVR chips. The structure of the `.ino` file usually looks like this:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "ESP8266WiFi.h"
##Some includes

void setup()
{
...
##Will be only run once at the begining.
}

void loop()
{
##Runs this code in a constant loop
}
```

My assumption is that somewhere behind simplification, before the compilation takes place, there is a `full blown source file`. It includes the platform specific initialization and contains the calls to `setup()` and `loop()`. When I say `full blown source file` I mean something that can be passed to the compiler and will compile given that the dependencies are met.

My questions are:

- Is this assumption correct?
- If so, can someone share an example on how does the `full blown source file` look like, and where did you get it from?

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/BuildProcess

Answer (score 6):

The Arduino core libraries (which are nothing more than a bunch of C/C++ files - there is no such thing as the "Arduino" programming language), are compiled along with your source code. These files include all of the initialisation routines and function definitions for things like `digitalWrite` and so forth.

There is a `main.cpp` file that gets compiled which is pretty much nothing more than:

```
#include "Arduino.h"

int main(void) {
    //Initialise timers and things (internal)
    init();
    //Your initialisation stuff (setup)
    setup();
    //Loop forever
    for (;;) {
        //Calling your loop function
        loop();
    }
}
```

In terms of what your `.ino` file becomes, it is basically just copied to a temporary build directory and renamed to `.cpp`. There are some minor changes made, which is basically to just copy all of the function declarations and place them at the top of the file.

This process is actually why if you use your own header file which has some `typedef` in it which you then use in a function call, the code will break because the declarations get added above the `#include` statements meaning the custom type is used before it is defined.

If you go to the preferences you can tell it to enable verbosity during compilation. This will actually show you exactly what is being compiled. It will also give you the path to the temporary build directory in which you will find the `.cpp` file with the same name as your `.ino` file.

Comment: `There are some minor changes made, which is basically to just copy all of the function declarations and place them at the top of the file. ` So the `.ino` file acts somewhat of a library. Makes sense. Will try to get to the `main.cpp` and expand your answer with the example after which I'll accept it.

Comment: Seems a little redundant to use "adruino" language, which then becomes C anyway.

Comment: @Serg despite what their website says, and the grand arguments about it, there is no such thing as the "Arduino" programming language, all it is is C++ with a little bit of badly conceived pre-processing.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I know, and that's exactly my point - why go to trouble of reinventing the wheel, when they could have just let people work in C/C++ directly ?

Answer (score 0):

C++ (the actual language/compiler that is used) is a multiple-compilation-unit language. There is no single source file, but rather a bundle of compiled source files, that are linked together to create the executable (or downloadable image).

In you case the user sketch provides the `setup()` and `loop()` functions, which are called from another source file, which is provided by the Arduino IDE.